# Veeam Backup (free version) can't find it's own server

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, veeam

I have a few servers that each have a few vm's on them. After running the install of the free version of veeam backup, I go into the program and add the new servers first. The servers run 2008 R2 Enterprise and I'm using the latest version of the free version of veeam backup.

The program basically says Network Path not found. It won't find it by name, ip address or even by using localhost.

What could the issue be? Could this be a credential issue? I am able with my user account to open the admin share just fine. I tried turning the firewall off on that server but it didn't make a difference.

Checking the log I find the following:

```
[08.12.2013 10:29:32] <68> Error    Access is denied
[08.12.2013 10:29:32] <68> Error    RPC function call failed. Function name: [GetSvcVersion]. Target machine: [192.168.2.1].
[08.12.2013 10:29:32] <95> Warning  [192.168.2.1] Failed to connect to Installer service on 192.168.2.1:6160. Reason: [192.168.2.1] Failed to check whether remote Installer service is available.   at Veeam.Backup.ProxyProvider.CDeployerService.TestConnection(String srvName, VeeamDeployer veeamDeployer)\n   at Veeam.Backup.ProxyProvider.CDeployerService.TryConnect(String srvName, VeeamDeployer veeamDeployer, String ip, Int32 port, Exception& exception)\nAccess is denied\nRPC function call failed. Function name: [GetSvcVersion]. Target machine: [192.168.2.1].   at VeeamProxyClientDllLib.VeeamDeployerClass.PingService()\n   at Veeam.Backup.ProxyProvider.CDeployerService.TestConnection(String srvName, VeeamDeployer veeamDeployer)
[08.12.2013 10:29:32] <95> Error    [192.168.2.1] Failed to check whether remote Installer service is available. (System.Exception)
[08.12.2013 10:29:32] <95> Error       at Veeam.Backup.ProxyProvider.CDeployerService.TestConnection(String srvName, VeeamDeployer veeamDeployer)
[08.12.2013 10:29:32] <95> Error       at Veeam.Backup.ProxyProvider.CDeployerService.TryConnect(String srvName, VeeamDeployer veeamDeployer, String ip, Int32 port, Exception& exception)
[08.12.2013 10:29:32] <95> Error    Access is denied\nRPC function call failed. Function name: [GetSvcVersion]. Target machine: [192.168.2.1]. (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
[08.12.2013 10:29:32] <95> Error       at VeeamProxyClientDllLib.VeeamDeployerClass.PingService()
[08.12.2013 10:29:32] <95> Error       at Veeam.Backup.ProxyProvider.CDeployerService.TestConnection(String srvName, VeeamDeployer veeamDeployer)
```

Comment: The servers you are trying to add are Hyper-V hosts, correct?

Comment: Yes, I've used it before and usually put the hosts. Then it finds all the VM's on that host and I can add them.

So guess what....I deleted my credentials and re-entered them in and it worked. Funny it would say can't find server when it was a credential issue.

A mod may delete this whole question/thread if he chooses.

Answer (score -1):

Even though you have found the root cause. There might be time-to-time difficulties if Veeam server and Hyper-V server aren't in the same domain, better to avoid it.